# How to merge multiple .RData using for loop in R?

Tags: r, merge, row

I have multiple `.RData` files in a folder. All samples have `10 rows` and `5 columns`

```
sample 1.RData
sample 2.RData
sample 3.RData
sample 4.RData
sample 5.RData
sample 6.RData
sample 7.RData
sample 8.RData
```

I can load them using the following code

```
seed.no=c(1:8)
    for ( ss in seed.no){
      #Load .RData
      sample=load.Rdata2(filename = paste0("sample",ss,".RData"))
       sample_all=rbind(sample)
    }
```

I would like to merge all data files row-wise as

```
  sample_all= rbind(sample 1.RData, sample 2.RData, sample 3.RData,sample 4.RData,sample 5.RData,sample 6.RData,sample 7.RData ,sample 8.RData).
```

`sample_all` should have `80 rows` and `5 columsn`.

Unfortunately `sample_all=rbind(sample)` is not giving me the expected results inside the loop.

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: I could not follow the answer, Can you please explain one more time?

Comment: You can do `do.call(rbind, lapply(paste0("sample", 1:8, ".RData"),  function(x) get(load.Rdata2(x))))`

Comment: In your `for` loop, you are just creating `sample` and then `rbind` the same object with itself.  Instead, the object needs to be updated

Comment: `Error in get(load.Rdata2(x)) : invalid first argument
Called from: get(load.Rdata2(x))`

Comment: Remove the `get` wrapped on it as it is not tested

Comment: Not sure if the `load.Rdata2` is from any package?

Comment: Now it is working.

Comment: Where does `load.Rdata2` come from?

Comment: use `miceadds` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the files namess, `load` the data and then `rbind` with `do.call`

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(paste0("sample", 1:8, ".RData"), load.Rdata2))
```

---

With a `for` loop, we can do the same thing

```
out1 <- data.frame()
for(rdata in paste0("sample", 1:8, ".RData")) {
       out1 <- rbind(out1, load.Rdata2(rdata))
}
```